# Views not showing

Tags: android, dji-sdk

Some of my views do not show up as if they have not been added to the viewgroup. I know they are created because I have references to them and can call methods on the variables. But they do not show.

The views work perfectly fine until I connect a dji drone to my app. I assume the dji library does too much work and android drops some of my views to keep up?

Any information pointing me in the right direction would be wonderful. Thanks.

**Edit** - A note: when a drone connects, I begin streaming video data from the camera to a textureview on the app. This is why I think the dji library could be doing too much work.

I guess my question is, is it possible that my views aren't showing up because so much work is being done elsewhere.

Comment: You should provide more details or code snippets. Your problem description is too vague to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue sending telemetry data from the flight controller to a textview with Android's setText.

An example would be like

```
Textview tv1 = findviewbyid(r.id.textview1);
tv1.setText(Float.toString(dronespeed));
```

This wouldn't work if I called it inside flight controller update callback. Instead, I set up a handler to receive the information every .5 seconds. You could maybe try something similar, but without more info about your code it would be hard to know what to do.